# Eloquent query not returning the expected result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use this eloquent query to query a table in my database with an array of values,

```
FlightRequest::where('public', 1)
->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
    $q->whereIn('departure', $query);
    $q->orWhereIn('arrival', $query);
})
->whereNull('acceptee_id')
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->get();
```

My `query` variable is an array of 2 values `['EGLL', 'EGKK']` in my `FlightRequest` table I have 1 row that has a public value of 1, a departure value of `EGLL`  and the acceptee_id is null yet that does not get returned.

I have tried a `dd` on the query and it returns this SQL statement

```
select * from `flight_requests` where `public` = 1 and (`departure` in ('EGLL', 'EGKK') or `arrival` in ('EGLL', 'EGKK')) and `acceptee_id` is null order by `id` asc
```

This statement should work and I do not know how it would be corrected to return what I want.

**Update**

I think the issue is now down to the departure and arrival columns being JSON columns casted to arrays. I effectivley need to query an each element in my `$query` array with each element in the departure and arrival JSON arrays.

I have tried doing

```
$q->orWhereJsonContains('departure', $query);
$q->orWhereJsonContains('arrival', $query);
```

but that only returns a row where the arrival column is `['EGLL', 'EGKK']` i.e. where both arrays are identical

Comment: You can see the generated SQL by using the `dd` method at the end instead of `get` Then you can run that SQL query directly so that maybe you can see what is wrong. And modify if needed.

Comment: @CanVural should have mentioned the query is as a result of a request as part of an API so a `dd` method would not work

Comment: That shouldn't matter. `dd` is not a solution I'm suggesting. Just to see the generated SQL and try to debug what is wrong. Cause currently it looks like the generated SQL is something like `"select * from "flight_requests" where "public" = 1 and ("departure" in ('EGLL', 'EGKK') or "arrival" in ('EGLL', 'EGKK')) and "acceptee_id" is null order by "id" asc"`  And it seems fine. 

Do you have any local or global scopes on the model?

Comment: @CanVural, no I dont have any scopes on the model, I know `dd` is not a solution but my issue is that I cannot actually see the generated SQL using `dd`

Comment: @CanVural I've updated the origional post with the generated SQL statement, I cannot work out what is wrong with it

Comment: Instead of ->get(); try to use ->toSql(); to see the generated query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
FlightRequest::where('public', 1)
->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
    foreach ($query as $apt) {
        $q->whereJsonContains('departure', $apt);
        $q->orWhereJsonContains('arrival', $apt);
    }
})
->whereNull('acceptee_id')
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
FlightRequest::where('public', 1)
->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
    $q->orWhereIn('departure', $query)->orWhereIn('arrival', $query);
})
->whereNull('acceptee_id')
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->get();
```

Comment: No luck with that answer

Comment: I think did not understand your question ... 
$query is an array ? 
and you wanna check both departure and arrival columns ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Would it be an issue that the departure and arrival columns are both JSON columns casted to an array in the model

Comment: If you are using NoSql you can use JSON operators, Besides if you use MySql you can use ```LIKE``` instead of ```=```

Comment: I am using MySQL, how can I integrate what you just said into my query

Comment: If you are saving JSON in your Database :
```orWhereIn('departure', LIKE,'%'.$query.'%')```
However, Im not sure about it but i think it works

Comment: That doesnt work as the `whereIn` method only takes 2 parameters, a column name and an array